# In Kitematic what does "connect to host network" mean?

Tags: docker, kitematic

In Kitematic, the following shows when going to `settings` > `network` on the official `mysql` container:

[image]

1. What does `connect to host network` mean? Every container has that setting.
2. What does `links` mean?

For example, PHP does not have anything in the `links` dropdown, while Nginx has MySQL and MySQL has Nginx.